# scrapy add data to the json file from different functions

Tags: python, json, function, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to both scrapy and json, and working on a scrapy project. this is my script:

```
import scrapy

class MoulaviSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "moulavi"

    def start_requests(self):
    start_urls = [
        'https://ganjoor.net/moulavi/masnavi/daftar1/sh1/',
        'https://ganjoor.net/moulavi/masnavi/daftar1/sh2/',
    ]
        for url in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.title)

    def title(self, response):
        #'hetitle': response.css('h2').extract(), 
        return scrapy.Request(callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for line in response.css('div.b'):
            yield {
                'right_column': line.css('div.m1').extract(),
                'left_column': line.css('div.m2').extract(),
}
```

And I run that with `scrapy crawl moulavi -o moulavi.json`.

I knom my scrpit is not correct for now.
I want to add the title of each page to the json file inside the **"def title"** and then call the **"def parse"** to add the other data to the json file. But as I'm not very familiar with callback or yield, so don't know what to do.

As you can see in my code, I have commented the line which is the spot I want the title be added into the json file, but don't know how to do that.

So what I want to do is to **scrape** the url, find the title of the page and then write it to the json file, and after that, start the for loop to find all div tags with class 'm1' and 'm2' and write them into the json file. And then start to scrape the next url.

I want to have output like this:  (not suro if the syntax is correct)

```
{
"title":"first page title",
"content":[
    {"right_column": ["<div class=\"m1\"><p>من چگونه هوش دارم پیش و پس</p></div>"], "left_column": ["<div class=\"m2\"><p>چون نباشد نور یارم پیش و پس</p></div>"]},
    {"right_column": ["<div class=\"m1\"><p>عشق خواهد کین سخن بیرون بود</p></div>"], "left_column": ["<div class=\"m2\"><p>آینه غماز نبود چون بود</p></div>"]},
    {"right_column": ["<div class=\"m1\"><p>آینت دانی چرا غماز نیست</p></div>"], "left_column": ["<div class=\"m2\"><p>زانک زنگار از رخش ممتاز نیست</p></div>"]}
]
"title":"second page title",
"content":[
    {"right_column": ["<div class=\"m1\"><p>بشنو این نی چون شکایت می‌کند</p></div>"], "left_column": ["<div class=\"m2\"><p>از جداییها حکایت می‌کند</p></div>"]},
    {"right_column": ["<div class=\"m1\"><p>کز نیستان تا مرا ببریده‌اند</p></div>"], "left_column": ["<div class=\"m2\"><p>در نفیرم مرد و زن نالیده‌اند</p></div>"]},
]}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: what is `url` in `scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)`. that code is not right because there is no variable called `url` in scope.

Comment: I know my script is not correct for now.

Comment: I just edited my script and removed that url part.

Comment: You want to pass values between functions and in the end return item with all properties collected?

Comment: I want to scrap the url, find the title of the page and then write it to the json file, and after that, start the for loop to find all div tags with class 'm1' and 'm2' and write them into the json file. And then start to scrape the next url.

Comment: You can do all this inside one function, after all you will get title of the same page that have items, right?

Comment: I don't get your question. look, there is a website that I want to scrape the first and the secned page of that. Each page has a different title, and some div elements with the same classnames that I should use for loop to collect them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need create new callback just to parse the title, you can create the structure that you want inside the `parse` function, what you need to do is simple create a object with the properties you want.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class MoulaviSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'moulavi'

    def start_requests(self):

        start_urls = [
            'https://ganjoor.net/moulavi/masnavi/daftar1/sh1/',
            'https://ganjoor.net/moulavi/masnavi/daftar1/sh2/',
        ]

        for url in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        item = dict(title=response.xpath('//title/text()').extract_first(),content=[])

        for line in response.css('div.b'):
            item['content'].append({
                'right_column': line.css('div.m1').extract_first(),
                'left_column': line.css('div.m2').extract_first()})

        yield item
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, a single method would be responsible for parsing the contents of a page, and then *yielding* the parsed data. At the end, after yielding all the items, this method could yield more Requests to further pages to be parsed if needed.

The parsed data would be used to create an instance of [Item](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html), and then then passed through an item pipeline for complex processing and persistence. Here, I'm sticking with yielding dictionaries to keep the example simpler.

From the desired output you provided, `content` is a top-level key in the output json, and it's value is a list. The list's element is a dictionary with two keys `left_column` & `right_column`, and the values are of type list.

In this case, the `parse` method *could* look like this:

```
import scrapy

class MoulaviSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "moulavi"

    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = [
            'https://ganjoor.net/moulavi/masnavi/daftar1/sh1/',
            'https://ganjoor.net/moulavi/masnavi/daftar1/sh2/',
        ]

        for url in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        # build up the content through a list comprehension
        # consider using `extract_first` instead of `extract` for 
        # less nested output
        content = [
          {'right_column': line.css('div.m1').extract(),
           'left_column': line.css('div.m2').extract()}
          for line in response.css('div.b')
        ]            
        yield {'title': response.css('h2').extract_first(),
               'content': content}
```

Note, that for extracting `title`, I used `extract_first` instead of extract. Consider using `extract_first` for the `left_column` & `right_column` values as well, as they seem to be lists of 1 element.